# Gedit continue indent

Tags: gedit

If I have the following (where the pipe is the cursor)

`(tab)123|`

and I press enter, I get:

`(tab)123
|`

But what I want to get is:

`(tab)123
(tab)|`

Is there a way to enable this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Preferences* → *Editor* and check "[✔] Enable automatic indentation".

(In GNOME 3, the Preferences option is in the <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> app menu.)

Alternatively, click the "Tab Width: 8" statusbar item and enable "Automatic indentation".

[image]